# How to take moving average of streaming data and take difference of consecutive moving average in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I want to calculate moving average and take difference of present average and previous average ,if difference between two consecutive moving average is greater than 4 add one is count counter.

my data is streaming data

with this function i can achieve moving average for offline data. but i am not sure how to do this for streaming data.

```
moving_avg= df['S1'].rolling(window=5).mean()
diff=df['moving_avg'].diff()
```

Comment: please share a sample of the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy to archive with the standard python collections.

The idea is to keep a limited [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) for your values and compute a simple average over that queue. `deque` uses linked list under the hood, so append performance is O(1).

Here is a simple example:

```py
from collections import deque

class Stats:
    def __init__(self, window=5):
        self._queue = deque(maxlen=window)
        self._prev_ma = None
        
    def push(self, value):
        self._queue.append(value)
        ma = sum(self._queue) / len(self._queue)
        diff = ma - self._prev_ma if self._prev_ma is not None else None
        self._prev_ma = ma
        print(f"value: {value}, MA: {ma}, diff: {diff}")

# usage
s = Stats()
for i in range(10):
    s.push(i)
```

Comment: thanks for your good solution. its possible to add one more condition here if diff is continuous greater than 2 for 5 rows need to trigger alarm?

Comment: of course, you can add any business logic inside the push method.